# `marshal data too short` error when executing a capybara test using poltergeist a few times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I've executed a decent capybara test using poltergeist as a driver like below a few times,

```
require 'spec_helper'

  describe 'Capybara test', js: true do
    it 'works' do
      visit '/'
    end
  end
```

I start to get an error "Marshal data too short" when reading the compiled JS file(?).
The backtrace is something like below.

```
1) Capybara test works
   Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
   ActionView::Template::Error:
     marshal data too short
   # ./app/views/layouts/_javascripts.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts__javascripts_html_erb__4483406095691079466_70112937186160'
   # ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__419483610520628071_70112936724940'
   # ./app/controllers/home_controller.rb:29:in `index'
```

./app/views/layouts/_javascripts.html.erb:7 is

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

and ./app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5 is

```
<%= render 'layouts/javascripts' %>
```

I've seen some couple questions asking why this happen when creating a AR object(which the actual reason is too much session data), but I think this is a different reason since it's happening when reading a JS file.

Any guess?

ref: [marshal data too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928204/marshal-data-too-short)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

rake tmp:clear solved the question.

Since there were no files under tmp/sessions, I didn't try out this command, but seems that the cache was triggering this problem.